# .NET Mono .app doesn't launch

Tags: c#, mono, osx-yosemite

So, I started with a compiled .exe file of my program, created in Windows MS Visual Studio, and was able to launch it via Mono by typing `mono InkMonitorClient.exe` in the terminal. Then I decided to pack it in a .dmg install file. First, I created an .app bundle via `macpack`. Then I used this [github script](https://github.com/silvansky/macscripts/blob/master/make_dmg.sh) to create a .dmg image.

The installer works as intended, the window appears in which I can drag my app to the Applications folder, and then it appears there.

But then I'm unable to launch it from the Applications menu in the Dock, although launching it by `open -a InkTest` or `/Applications/InkTest.app/Contents/MacOS/InkTest` works absolutely fine.

P.S. The .app file, however, fails to launch by double-clicking and does nothing, but opening it it Terminal (as stated above) works. So, basically, the question is: how to correctly convert .NET (created in MS Visual Studio on Windows) exe file to app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The macpac tool is for Cocoa# applications, i.e. those built using the Mac Cacoa framework. Unfortunately simply putting an exe built with Win Forms or GTK# does not work, displaying all the characteristics you describe, I have burned hours of my life on that one. See bottom of http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/.

If your application comprises multiple .dlls and an .exe you could use ILRepack to package up everything into a single .exe for tidiness. Additionally, it's not ideal, but you could also supply a launcher file (.command file on mac) with your app to save a manual launch from terminal.